# Navigation drop down menu not showing using simple css and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu list made in css and plain HTMl. It works fine but it rolls under my image slider , and I can see on a part of the menu when i hover on any of my menu. I think z-index property is missing somewhere. But I used in my ul li tag but no use.

html

```
<ul id="menu">
                  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">About Us</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">The Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Products</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Cozy Couch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Great Table</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Small Chair</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Shiny Shelf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Invisible Nothing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Contact</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Online</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Right Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Somewhere Else</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
```

css

```
ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { background: #617F8A; }
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #617F8A; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #95A9B1; }
```

Comment: please post a question. A question contains a ?

Comment: Yea, we'll need to see code. I'll take a shot in the dark though and suggest that you need to use `z-index`.

Comment: @will where should I add z-index..in javascript or CSS

Comment: li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;z-index:100
}

Comment: @NicholasKing THANKS..THAT WORKED....i HAD USED z-index:1000px...

Comment: @Mckenzi z-index is just the number of layer you want to put an element in. nothing more or less than that. :)

Answer (score 1):

image slider has z-index property from java-script. so it will take high priority.
You need to give z-index to your navigation also.

Is your image slider having jQuery?
Than you have to put z-index in li ul `li{z-index:999px;}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add z-index to the following class.

```
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Also make sure that the z-index for the menu is having higher property.